# What is the proper way to animate a UIView from outside of a view controller into it's center?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I have several `UIButton`s that animate from the right (outside the bounds of the view controller) into the center of my view controller each time I press a button. I'm currently accomplishing this by animating the .centerX constraint constant of each `UIButton` from 250 to 0. It works, but the buttons are visible on the right side devices with larger screens. I could just increase the constant to 300 or something, but isn't there a proper way to accomplish this using Auto-Layout?

Comment: Pet peeve - questions that do not clearly show that there's a difference between a `UIView` (which has bounds) and a `UIViewController`. (Sorry.) Why not do things with 100% auto layout? If your `UIView` needs to move in from the right, set it's `leadingAnchor to be a constant of xFactor to it's superview's `trailingAnchor` edge. And if you need to space out multiple `UIViews` off screen, do that first (line up the `UIViews` in auto layout) and set the *first* `leadingAnchor` equal to the multiple views superview `trailingAnchor`?

Answer (score 0):

you can align button's leading edge with VC.view's trailing edge and then animate it by translating along x axis.

Comment: What do you mean by “translating”?